# Visual Studio 2017 15.5 Linux CMake project Linux includes

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio-2017

I am using the Visual Studio 2017 15.5 CMake to develop a Linux application ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/25/visual-c-for-linux-development-with-cmake/)).  I am using some libraries and includes that were installed via `apt-get` on a Ubuntu system.  I would like the Intellisense in Visual Studio to work with these additional includes.  It appears that some Linux system includes exist in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\include`

I have copied the additional includes into this directory and Visual Studio Intellisense is working well.  Is this best way to do this or is there a better or accepted approach?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of visual studio 15.5, However, I would expect there is a 'search path' environment variable that tells the 'intellisense' where to look for the header files.

Comment: You will not normal put third-party headers in system folders, if for no other reason than installers freely overwrite these locations. However, it looks like there's a problem with IntelliSense and CMake projects, see https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/195. You might want to add your scenario to that VSLinux issue. But it looks like you're stuck with the workaround you've found in the short-term.

Comment: I share the same concern about files getting overwritten or otherwise mangling the system.  I was hoping there might be a configuration file (e.g. cppproperties.json) or setting in Visual Studio where I could point it to another directory.  Since this is an "Open Folder" project, I do not seem to be able to set additional includes in the project properties, etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Continuing to use my initial solution.